# Set value in a datagridview cell programmatically

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm new in C# and I have a problem with setting the value of a cell programmatically.

I've created a column and added it to the DataGridView:

```
  DataGridViewTextBoxColumn column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
  column.Name = "DeclaredBy";
  column.HeaderText = "DeclaredBy";
  TaskDataGridView.Columns.Add(column);
```

The column shows up correctly. But when I want to set a value in any cell of this column, nothing happens, the cell is still empty:

```
TaskDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["DeclaredBy"].Value = "test";
```

Comment: Are you working on a WinForms application?

Comment: Yes, the datagridview is in a win form.

Answer (score 0):

```
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
column.Name = "DeclaredBy";
column.HeaderText = "DeclaredBy";
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column);
dataGridView1.Rows.Add("test value");
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["DeclaredBy"].Value = "changed test value";
```

This is working. Try on newly created `DataGridView`, without any columns at all. If that will work, probably you made some changes on your `DataGridView` that disallow changing value. Ofc, when you run this, you will see only `"changed test value"`, but this is also working, when the last line is under another button. Another possible solution is that maybe your `i` is not the one you want to.